# Explanation of how is the variable "leaking"?

Tags: javascript

I was reading about hoisting in mozilla, and noticed an example explaining how a variable can leak outside of the function scope: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Initialization_of_several_variables

The example says,

```
var x = 0;

function f(){
  var x = y = 1; // x is declared locally. y is not!
}
f();

console.log(x, y); // 0, 1
// x is the global one as expected
// y leaked outside of the function, though!
```

I don't understand what is happening here. I am looking for a technical explanation more than anything. How is y accessible outside at this point?

Edit: I understand how this function is behaving, and I should clarify and say I wanted an understanding of what is happening in the code and memory (ex, pointers, etc..).

Comment: Because it isn't prefixed with `var`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var - *"Assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a global variable "*

Answer (score 4):

This is breakdown of the statement:

```
   var x = y = 1;
   \___/   \____/
identifier initializer 
   \____________/
  variable declaration
```

In this case the initializer is another assignment. Due to variable hoisting, this statement is evaluated as follows:

```
var x;
x = y = 1;
```

As you can see, `y` is not declared. *Assigning* to an *undeclared* variable creates a global variable (implicitly).

Answer (score 3):

you have `var x = y = 1` which means that x is declared inside but y is not, `var` doesn't apply to y in this case, that's why it's leaked outside the function

Comment: but then too if you do `var x, y=1` and do console ,still shows `0,1`

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava it shows Uncaught ReferenceError: y is not defined for me, because y is not defined outside the function when you do declare it that way

Comment: my bad ,first function make `y` as global now so everytime it prints `1`

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = 0;

function f(){
  var y = 1; 
  var x = 1; 
}
f();

console.log(x, y);
```

Try the above code. The problem is that you didn't include a var in front of y. The result is that y is hoisted into global scope.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, variables are declared as soon as you use them, like this:

```
function f(){
  y = 1;
}
```

The problem is that y is not `scoped` within f(), like it would be in most other programming languages. So you can do something like this:

```
function f(){
  y = 1;
}

console.log(y);
```

And you will see `1` on the console.

This is generally considered a bad practice, because it pollutes your namespace and can lead to subtle, hard to track down bugs.

To avoid this, always use `let` or `var` to explicitly declare variables, like this:

```
function f(){
  let y = 1;
}

// the y declared in f() is not accessible out here
console.log(y)
```

This should give you an error like: "Uncaught ReferenceError: y is not defined" on your console.

For more details, read this page, specifically the section 'Automatically Global': http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

In the example you gave above the problem is more subtle, because x is scoped properly, but the short-hand declaration of y makes it globally scoped:

```
function f(){
  let x = y = 1;
}
```

EDIT 2022: Updated to recommend `let` over `var`. [Here is an explanation of the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var).